# display:none and inline-block at the same time

Tags: jquery, html

I want to use **display:inline-block** for div element and the same time to do its invisible with **display:none**. Is it right?

```
div {display:inline-block;display:none;}
```

Comment: It doesn't matter if its `inline-block` or not when its not displayed. Right?

Comment: Yes, although `display: inline-block` would have no effect, after all it's set as `display: none`, thus disregarding any DOM rules set on that element. If you want the `<div>` to still have an *effect* on the DOM, despite being hidden use `visibility: hidden;`

Comment: you want to change it later with jquery?

Comment: see my answer ..added a jsfiddle. If you want to toggle (e.g. make it visible, then invisible again), then reply, and will make a working example

Comment: @Acelasi Eu finally I chosen your variant.. thank you guy =)

Comment: No problem:) Make sure you accept the answer, so that others searching can find it easily :)

Comment: @Acelasi for a long time been looking for how to do this)

Comment: @user3073240 http://jsfiddle.net/7seWm/2/ here is an update fiddle with toggle too ( so that you can hide it by the link again)

Comment: maybe onload function hides the element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: working jsfiddle with toggle: [jsfiddle.net/7seWm/2](http://jsfiddle.net/7seWm/2)

working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7seWm/

if you want to change it with jquery, use this:

css:

```
div {display:none;}
```

jquery:

```
$("#divid").css("display", "inline-block");
```

Answer (score 6):

It's not possible. Because last value of `display` property will be taken.

I think you want to display div inline but hide it right? 
So:

```
div { 
    display:inline-block;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Note: Using Jquery with this CSS, instead of `$('div').show();` you need to use `$('div').css('visibility', 'visible');` ... Alternative solution: Set CSS with `display:inline-block;` and then use Jquery to hide() the div.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a hide class to control the visibility, like this:

Css

```
div {display:inline-block;}
.hide{display:none;}
```

Html

```
<div>inline</div>
<div class="hide">hide</div>
```

Javascript:

```
 div.classList.add('hide');
 div.classList.remove('hide');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9zmGu/1/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide it, but he also take the space, use your display rule and `visibility:hidden`